# Touch event methods are not calling in UIPopOverViewController in ipad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios4, ios6

Hi Iam working with `UIPopOverViewController` in ipad app. I called touches event methods, off course those are automatically called when touch. But those are `UIView` methods. My problem is I have popOverViewController, in that image-view. when i touch in that image-view, delegate methods are not called.

I do it in another way, it is i sub-view the image view in `UIView`, in this case delegates are called. when i assigned that image-view to PopOverView, delegates are not called.

here is the sample code :

```
 if(popOverViewBool) {

 signatureImageView.image=nil;
 [currentTextField resignFirstResponder];
 [currentTextView resignFirstResponder];
 red = 0.0/255.0;
 green = 0.0/255.0;
 blue = 0.0/255.0;
 brush = 2.2;//10.0
 opacity = 1.0;


 UIViewController* popOverVCont = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
 popOverVCont.view=myView;
 popOverVCont.contentSizeForViewInPopover =CGSizeMake(590, 350);

 self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
 initWithContentViewController:popOverVCont];

 popoverController.delegate = self;

 [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(-137, 460, 320, 10) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
 popOverViewBool=NO;
 }
 else
 {
 [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(-137, 460, 320, 10) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
 }



- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

mouseSwiped = NO;
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
//lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.drawSignView];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

mouseSwiped = YES;
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
//CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.drawSignView];

//UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.drawSignView.frame.size);


//[self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.drawSignView.frame.size.width, self.drawSignView.frame.size.height)];
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush );
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);

CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
[self.tempDrawImage setAlpha:opacity];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

lastPoint = currentPoint;
 }

 - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

if(!mouseSwiped)
{
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.drawSignView.frame.size);


    //[self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.drawSignView.frame.size.width, self.drawSignView.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, opacity);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mainImage.frame.size);
//[self.mainImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
[self.mainImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.drawSignView.frame.size.width, self.drawSignView.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];


//[self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:opacity];
[self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.drawSignView.frame.size.width, self.drawSignView.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:opacity];
self.mainImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
self.tempDrawImage.image = nil;
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

i Google it, but i did not find any answer..
Please give any ideas or suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Have you check your UIImageview userInterfaceEnable property is true or not?

Comment: yes, i tried to set both Yes and NO, but no use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `touches*` series in your view, you gotta make custom class that implements that methods.

1. In your case, you have to make `SomeImageView` class which is subclass of `UIImageView`.
2. Or you can use subclasses of  `UIGestureRecognizer` like `UITapGestureRecognizer` or `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`.  in your `viewDidLoad` of controller,

   ```
   self.tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
   self.tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
   self.tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
   self.tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1; // invoked at 1 tap. 
   self.photoScaleFrameView addGestureRecognizer:self.tapGestureRecognizer];
   ```

and in your controller.m

```
    - (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
           NSLog(@"tap gesture detected");
    }
```

and bam.

Comment: Thank you @steven kim. i took separate viewcontroller called PoPOverVC and subview that PoPOverVC to POpOverViewcontroller. I wrote touches methods in PoPOverVC itself. then they was called. now it is working fine. Thank you very much.